# Linq return only elements where contained list are matching

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have conversation table with list of mebers who belong conversation and now I whant search conversation by list of members.

Conversation class

```
class Conversation{ 

     public IList<Member> Members {get; set}

     public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
}
```

Member class

```
class Member{

     public Conversation {get; set;}

     public User {get; set;}
 }
```

And I have method (Use NHibernate)

```
public Conversation GetByMembers(IList<Member> members){
     return repositort.Query().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Members.Intersect(members).Count() == members.Count);

}
```

Does anyone know how to do it using LINQ?

**Update**: What I want to accomplish is to see if there is already conversation with exact conversation members and reopen it instead of creating a new conversation for provided members.

Comment: add code to the question please...

Comment: Can you share your code and also what you have tried? I would assume it is possible with linq but you haven't given enough details to help you.

Comment: _"...conversation table with list of mebers"_  Do you think that this helps to understand your question? Please make more of an effort.

Comment: You _are_ using linq. So what's the actual question? I suspect it does not do what you expected, but then you should tell us why.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean this:

```
query.Where(c=>list.Contains(c.Attribute));
```

Comment: -1: What exactly is the point in answering with a counter-question, which is really one line of code and cannot possibly be representative of the solution because we have no information about the data model?

Comment: This should be the comment probably?